# How to remove scrollbar from kendo editor text area

Tags: kendo-editor

I have a Kendo Editor defined as below:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Editor()
      .Name("myEditor")
      .Tag("div")
      .Tools(tools => tools
            .Clear()
            .Bold().Italic().Underline().Strikethrough()
            .JustifyLeft().JustifyCenter().JustifyRight().JustifyFull()
            .CreateLink().Unlink()
            .InsertImage()
            .TableEditing()
            .FontColor().BackColor()
      )
      .Value(@<text><p>Some content here</p></text>)
  )
```

When I run my code, a horizontal scrollbar appears at the bottom of the editor.

I want to remove the horizontal scrollbar. How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I got an answer to my own question. Adding class = "container-fluid" to my div helped.

Thanks!

Comment: this class in some tempaltes or themes not work, so this not looks any of suitable answer